# What's the best way to create a subtle, barely noticeable texture?

Tags: gimp, patterns, free

Using Gimp (or other free software), how would I go about creating a subtle, "mild" texture, like the green in the header at [forrst](http://forrst.com/), or the gray in the background of the [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) home page?

Those textures seem random and very evenly distributed.

Comment: could you include a screenshot of the visuals you are looking for? they sites are most surely changing over time.

Answer (score 3):

The basic technique is to create a background color or gradient, add a 50% Grey layer above it with its blend mode set to "Overlay" and add some noise to that layer using whatever method your program provides. In Photoshop it's a filter, and I seem to recall it's much the same in the gimp. Adjust the amount of noise (which should be monochromatic) and opacity to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the noise filter to create a low opacity overlay/burn texture layer. Blamo!